# Is there a way to better reformat my weapon and armor classes for improved readability?

Tags: python

I have the two classes:

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, Type, quality, material, dmg, name):
        self.Type = Type
        self.quality = quality
        self.name = name
        self.material = material
        self.identify = 'Melee weapon'
    def displayinvent(self):
        print(f'{self.quality} quality {self.material} {self.Type} {self.name}'.center(150))
    def display(self):
        print(f"{self.material} {self.name}")

class Armour:
    def __init__(self, quality, material, armour, name):
        self.quality = quality
        self.armour = armour
        self.name = name
        self.material = material
        self.identify = 'armour'
    def displayinvent(self):
        print(f'{self.quality} quality {self.material} {self.name} with defense of {self.armour}'.center(150))
    def display(self):
        print(f"{self.material} {self.name}")
```

It comes up as:

```
                                                  <skill.Weapon object at 0x7f89696d6640>(1)                                                      
                                                  <skill.Weapon object at 0x7f89696d6220>(2)                                                      
                                                  <skill.Weapon object at 0x7f89696d65b0>(3)                                                      
                                                  <skill.Weapon object at 0x7f89695e6b20>(4)                                                      
                                                  <skill.Armour object at 0x7f89695e66a0>(5)                                                      
                                                  <skill.Armour object at 0x7f89695e6c40>(6)                                                      
                                                  <skill.Armour object at 0x7f89695e6ca0>(7)                                                      
                                                  <skill.Armour object at 0x7f89695e6d00>(8)
```

I am aware of the **str** and **repr** methods but do not understand them and am not sure about any other methods.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reading about the `__str__`? Some examples here could get you started: https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-str-method-in-python

Comment: _"am aware of the str and repr methods but do not understand them"_: did you read the documentation or any tutorials on these methods? What specifically do you not understand? You already know the answer, you just need to [do some research!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/843953)

Comment: How do you create these objects and print them?  It doesn't look like you're calling your `display` methods, but the output is still centered weirdly, so you're not just printing the objects themselves on their own either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the common code to a base class, to avoid repeating the code.

Put the printing method there: `__str__`

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Gear(dict): # Make Gear a dictionary, so it can store
                  # all kind of properties, to be printed together.
    # quality, material, name are common to Armor and Weapon
    def __init__(self, quality, material, name):
        self.update({'quality': quality, 'material': material, 'name': name})

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def identify(self) -> str:
        # identify() is different for armor and weapo, then here
        # is declared as an abstract method, so you know that 
        # you have to implement identiyfy() each time you create a Gear 
        # type class, like Weapon or Armor

        # Each inheriting class has to provide this property
        # it has to return a string that identifies the gear
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def displayinvent(self):
        # Each inheriting class has to provide this property
        # it has to return a string that displays the gear
        pass

    def display(self):
        #This method is the same in Weapon and Armor, so is better to be in Gear
        print(f'{self["material"]} {self["name"]}')

    # Here the code that will be printed when the object is printed
    def __str__(self):
        return "".join([f"{key}: {value}\n" for key, value in self.items()])
```

Now, `Weapon` and `Armor` can inherit from `Gear`:

```
class Weapon(Gear):
    def __init__(self, Type, quality, material, dmg, name):
        super().__init__(quality, material, name)  # <- Will initialize as Gear
        # Type is exclusive to Weapon (not to Armor), so is coded here
        self["Type"] = Type
        # damage is exclusive to Weapon (not to Armor), so is coded here
        self["damage"] = dmg

    def displayinvent(self):
        print(
            f'{self["quality"]} quality {self["material"]} {self["Type"]} {self["name"]}'.center(150))

    def identify(self) -> str:
        return 'Melee weapon'


class Armour(Gear):
    def __init__(self, quality, material, armour, name):
        super().__init__(quality, material, name)  # <- Will initialize as Gear
        # armour is exclusive to Armour (not to Weapon), so is coded here
        self['armour'] = armour

    def displayinvent(self):
        print(
            f'{self["quality"]} quality {self["name"]} with defense of {self["armour"]}'.center(150))

    def identify(self) -> str:
        return 'armour'


myArmor = Armour('good', 'steel', 'jacket', 'Sacred Armor of destruction')
myWeapon = Weapon('sword', 'good', 'steel', 60, 'Cutter of Poltergeist')

print(myArmor)
print(myWeapon)

myArmor.display()
myArmor.displayinvent()
myWeapon.display()
myWeapon.displayinvent()

>>> quality: good
>>> material: steel
>>> name: Sacred Armor of destruction
>>> armour: jacket

>>> quality: good
>>> material: steel
>>> name: Cutter of Poltergeist
>>> Type: sword
>>> damage: 60

>>> steel Sacred Armor of destruction
>>>                                            good quality Sacred Armor of destruction with defense of jacket

>>> steel Cutter of Poltergeist
>>>                                                     good quality steel sword Cutter of Poltergeist
```